# DHCP snooping problem

Tags: cisco, switch, router, dhcp-snooping

I have some problems with a very simple DHCP snooping configuration.

[image: My topology]

I'm using a very simple topology using router on a stick. I use VLAN 10 and VLAN 20.

My Clients can get DHCP from my router when dhcp snooping is not enabled on my switch, but when I enable snooping they can no longer get an IP.

My switch has interface f0/6 and f0/11 as access ports, f0/6 is on vlan 10 and f0/11 is on vlan 20. f0/1 is in trunking mode.

My switch config:

```
Switch DHCP snooping is enabled
DHCP snooping is configured on following VLANs:
1-100
Insertion of option 82 is enabled
Option 82 on untrusted port is not allowed
Verification of hwaddr field is enabled
Interface                  Trusted    Rate limit (pps)
-----------------------    -------    ----------------
FastEthernet0/1            yes        unlimited
```

I have full connectivity when DHCP snooping is not enabled so I'm only asking why it doesn't work when snooping is enabled.

My "show run" config on switch:

```
!
ip dhcp relay information trust-all
!
ip dhcp snooping vlan 1-100
ip dhcp snooping
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk native vlan 99
 ip dhcp snooping trust
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 no ip address
 ip helper-address 192.168.1.1
!
interface Vlan20
 no ip address
 ip helper-address 192.168.2.1
!
interface Vlan99
 ip address 192.168.99.99 255.255.255.0
!
end
```

My "show run" config on router:

```
ip dhcp relay information trust-all
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN10
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.1.1
ip dhcp pool VLAN20
 network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.2.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Interface f0/1 needs to be marked as trusted. Could you supply full configuration to verify.

Comment: Well my g0/0 is on my router, DHCP snooping is configured on my switch.  interface FastEthernet0/1 is configured with native vlan 99, ip dhcp snooping trust, switchport mode trunk

Comment: I have added relevant configuration to my question.

Comment: Could you please supply with output:
#sh ip dhcp snooping

Comment: I already gave you the output of "show ip dhcp snooping" on my switch.

Comment: It seems that snooping is not applied on vlan 20 and 10.
Port FastEthernet0/6 and FastEthernet0/10 should be displayed as untrusted ports.

Comment: Excuse me, but do you have any experience or knowledge on DHCP snooping? It seems to me that you are rather clueless.

Comment: Trying to help you with troubleshooting. 
Issue command:
#ip dhcp snooping vlan 10,20,99
Please supply output 
#show ip dhcp snooping binding

Comment: I tried. PC: "DHCP failed. APIPA is being used." It doesn't help..

Comment: Last option is to add #ip dhcp snooping information option allow-untrusted
Maybe this is issue with option 82. But usually you would switch on this option at aggregation layer towards edge.

Comment: DHCP requests still failing

Comment: Try to remove ip helper-address on both vlan interfaces as they are not need.
#no interface vlan 10
#no interface vlan 20

Comment: nope, not it. Btw it's much easier to just do #no ip helper-address instead of removing the interface ...

Comment: in this case SVI is not required. Is that GNS3 lab? is command #show ip dhcp snooping binding 
display any bindings?

Comment: please supply output for #show ver on switch1

Comment: Why is SVI not required? Please elaborate.

Comment: As in this case you are using router on a stick. Vlan spanning up to router thru 802.1q trunk and first Switch doesn't do any Layer 3 operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43797/discussion-between-bungicasse-and-datagram-network).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation with packet tracer it seems. I quickly replicated your set up in PT 7.0 with no luck.

If you put a server on a new switchport, put the port on the correct vlan and mark that port as trusted DHCP will work fine. I think if you did this with real kit it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following command, your problem will be solved.

```
 no ip dhcp snooping information option
```

for example,my configuration:

```
sw1-f1-msh-p#show run | s snooping 
ip dhcp snooping vlan 201,706,3200-3272 
no ip dhcp snooping information option 
ip dhcp snooping trust
```

Comment: You should include that `no ip dhcp snooping information option` disables the (default) option 82 insertion used for DHCP relaying, see @eriktm's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using DHCP snooping, I have often seen that you need to apply the following command to disable the relaying of DHCP option 82 to the DHCP server for it to actually work. Unless, of course, your DHCP server is set up with regards to option 82, which it is not in your case.

```
no ip dhcp snooping information option
```

Comment: Trust me I have tried and it still doesn't work. It might be Cisco Packet Tracer having problems

Comment: @Bungicasse just to be certain, I set up your configuration with a physical router and switch in the lab, and everything worked just fine with both VLANs. I also did some various configuration changes (option 82, relay trust, etc) and it still worked. This would indicate there might be an issue with the Packet Tracer as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the router.  The debug below tells you if it is receiving DHCP requests. [source [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/27470-100.html#tshootunabletoobtain)]

> In global configuration mode, enter the following access-list:
>
> ```
> access-list 100 permit ip host 0.0.0.0 host 255.255.255.255
> ```
>
> In exec mode, enter the following debug command:
>
> ```
> debug ip packet detail 100
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> Router#debug ip packet detail 100
> IP packet debugging is on (detailed) for access list 100
> Router#
> 00:16:46: IP: s=0.0.0.0 (Ethernet4/0), d=255.255.255.255, len 604, rcvd 2
> 00:16:46: UDP src=68, dst=67
> 00:16:46: IP: s=0.0.0.0 (Ethernet4/0), d=255.255.255.255, len 604, rcvd 2
> 00:16:46: UDP src=68, dst=67
> ```